# Using AutoForm with Angular Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm new to using Angular with Meteor (using [`angular-with-blaze`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/angular-with-blaze)) and have used [`AutoForm`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/) previously with Blaze.

When creating the autoForm of `type="update"`, an object must be passed in as the `doc` parameter

```
{{#autoForm collection="Fruits" id="updateFruit" type="update" doc=fruit}}
    ...
{{/autoForm}}
```

**Question:** How can I pass the document `fruit` to the `autoForm` helper? Should I be using Angular controllers or Blaze Template Helpers?

I'm also using `ui.router`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('editFruit', {
        url: '/editFruit/:fruit_id',
        templateUrl: 'client/fruits/views/edit-fruit.ng.html'
    })
```

---

### Update

Attempted to use Blaze's template helpers but it does not seem to be passing the object to the Blaze template. Maybe this feature have not been implemented or maybe my code is incorrect.

```
Template.updateFruitForm.helpers({
    fruit: function () {
        var href = window.location.href ;
        var fruit_id = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        return Fruits.findOne({_id: fruit_id});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a section about sending parameters to Blaze templates inside the  directive here - 
http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.1/blaze-template#passingargumentstoblazetemplate

Basically you will need to:

1. Create a new Blaze template that includes the template you want to include
2. Add the parameters to the new template
3. Include that new template with blaze-template